# macOS Catalina: "App is damaged and can't be opened. You should move it to the trash."

Tags: macos, catalina, code-signing, gatekeeper

Experiencing a problem with several apps after installing macOS Catalina.

When the app is downloaded from the internet I get the error:

> "APP NAME" is damaged and can't be opened. You should move it to the trash.

Any workarounds to bypass macOS gatekeeper for specific apps?

[image: "APP NAME" is damaged and can't be opened. You should move it to the trash.]

Comment: Open App by overriding security settings:

`In Finder Ctrl+Click the app icon -> choose Open from shortcut menu -> Click Open.` 

The app is saved as the exception to your security settings, and your could open it from now on.

Answer (score 57):

Here's the solution. Open Terminal and run:

```
sudo xattr -rds com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Coherence\ Pro.app
```

If the path to the program is different, then obviously change it so that it's pointing to your app. For me, I've had several apps not working after the update to macOS Catalina. This takes care of that problem though.

Here's more info about `xattr` and what the flags mean.
https://ss64.com/osx/xattr.html

Comment: For me, I need additional flag: sudo xattr -rds com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Coherence\ Pro.app in order to work. The differences are: '-rd' to '-rds'

Comment: Simpler solution is `xattr -cr Coherence\ Pro.app`