# You can't open the application "Transmission.app" because it may be damaged or incomplete

Tags: macos, catalina, gatekeeper

I upgraded from MacOs 10.14 to 10.15 (Catalina), now I can't open Transmission. I get the following error:

> You can't open the application "Transmission.app" because it may be damaged or incomplete.

[image]

1. I tried reinstalling it both from the website and from homebrew.
2. I tried the `xattr` command mentioned in [this Ask Different post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372084/macos-catalina-app-is-damaged-and-cant-be-opened-you-should-move-it-to-the-t), i.e.

```
    sudo xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Transmission.app
```

3. I tried "Allow apps downloaded from anywhere", but still get the same error message.

[image]

Comment: If you right click Transmission.app and choose open, does it allow you to? I'm guessing not based on the other things you tried, but worth a shot.

Comment: @EzekielElin Same error :(

Comment: Have you got the latest version of Transmission v3.0?

Comment: What happens if you run in Terminal: `/Applications/Transmission.app/Contents/MacOS/Transmission` ?

Comment: Hmm, it may be nothing, but I spotted something odd in your screenshot of System Preferences. The Pref Pane is currently _unlocked_, but the "Allow apps downloaded from:" radio buttons are still grayed out. If I'm not forgetting something obvious, this could be a clue to what's happening, although I don't know what it means...

Comment: Also, Catalina doesn't have any Anywhere option by default which means some settings have definitely been played with

Comment: @EzekielElin I ran `sudo spctl --master-disable` to get the `Anywhere` option. I read a guide somewhere that said to do it.

Comment: @mmmmmm Yes, I have the latest version

Comment: @Wowfunhappy, There is nothing inside the `MacOS` directory on my machine.

Comment: @Morgoth The MacOS directory is your problem - it needs something inside it to be properly executable. Transmission.app should be about 12.9 MB and the MacOS directory should have a 1.3 MB file inside it.

Comment: @EzekielElin. If I reinstall transmission there is a `Transmission` executable inside `/Applications/Transmission.app/Contents/MacOS/`, when I try to run it I get '"Transmission.app" cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.', then the executable is automatically deleted.