# "You should move it to the Trash." Is there a way I can add an app to a whitelist so that my Mac allow me to use this particular app?

Tags: security

Per a [tutorial](https://iboysoft.com/howto/apple-cannot-check-it-for-malicious-software.html), when trying to open apps from unknown sources, macOS gives me an option "Open Anyway".

[image]

However, my macOS 13.3 doesn't give that option to me

[image]

instead, it gives "will damage your computer. You should move it to the Trash."

[image]

I tried this command from an [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/372208/502751)

```
sudo xattr -rds com.apple.quarantine /Applications/
```

Is there a way I can add an app to a whitelist so that my Mac allow me to use this particular app? or workaround, such as adding date?

Comment: Right-Click and „Open“ should launch it the first time. Afterwards just use double-click.

Comment: It may be that the app has been modified in some way that breaks its code-signing. (Instead of it being completely unsigned.) Have you tried downloading a new copy of the app from the developer again?

Comment: Which application is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a [support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491) on this. It differentiates between "software has malicious content or its authorization has been revoked for any reason" and "software that hasn’t been signed and notarized", only the second can be overruled.